# Cancelar envio de formulario a servlet

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Cordial saludo,

Tengo problemas tratando de validar el formulario a enviar un formulario al servlet, estoy acudiendo a validación por JavaScript, pero aunque retorne false al formulario en la etiqueta onsubmit, el formulario igual se procesa en el servlet. Aclaro que ya comprobe que ingresa correctamente al condicional que retorna el false mediante un alert, pero aún así de nuevo se procesa el formulario.

Muchas gracias por su atencion.

HTML:

```
<form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/RegistrarVehiculoServlet" method="POST" onsubmit="validarForm()"> . . .</form>
```

JS:

```
function validarForm(){
            var placa = document.getElementById('placa').value;
            var marca = document.getElementById('marca').value;
            var modelo = document.getElementById('modelo').value;
            var fecha = document.getElementById('fechaIngreso').value;
            if (placa === "" || marca === "" || modelo === "" || fecha === "") {
                alert("Completa todos los campos");
                return false;
            }else{ return true;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta incluir la instrucción `return`:

```
<form action=... onsubmit="return validarForm()"> . . .</form>
```

De esta forma si `validarForm` devuelve `false` el envío del formulario se cancelará.

Comment: Funciona a la perfección, muchisimas gracias, pensé que solo con el return de la función bastaba.